# Remove duplicates from each cell

Tags: python, perl, awk

I have a file like this and need to remove duplicates in each cell without changing the order or format

```
Sl.no Name1 Name2  Dis  From  Type      item    Animal         Code
 2    qw     wsa   12    23   car,car   Case    CAT1,CAT1,Dog  p.12>a,p.12>a
23    as     swe   34    2,2  Bus,Bus   Case1,, Dog1,Dog1,,    N.12>a,N.12>a
23    ks     awe   35    .    Bike,Bike Case1,, rat4,rat4,,    5.16>b,5.16>b
```

The missing data are noted as . (dot).

So far I have tried  with awk

```
 awk '{str="";c=0;split($0,arr,","); for (v in arr) c++; for (m=c;m >= 1;m--) for (n=1; n<m;n++) if (arr[m] == arr[n]) delete arr[m]; for (k=1;k<=c;k++) {if (k ==1 ) {s=arr[k] } else if (arr[k] != "") str=str" "arr[k] } print str}'
```

But it is killing the format. Is there any other way to do this ?

Expected output

```
Sl.no Name1 Name2  Dis  From  Type      item    Animal        Code
 2    qw     wsa   12    23   car       Case    CAT1,Dog    p.12>a
23    as     swe   34    2    Bus       Case1   Dog1        N.12>a
23    ks     awe   35    .    Bike      Case1   rat4        5.16>b
```

Comment: Is the file space padded (fixed width) or tab padded? Both your current answers depend on a different version of your file.

Comment: Having "From" in the header line start 1 character sooner than the data values below it and having "Code" be right-aligned when everything else is left-aligned is messy. Are you sure you want that?

Comment: You should include cells with duplicates in other positions than the first 2, e.g. `foo,bar,foo` and `foo,bar,bar` as you're getting some answers that'll produce the expected output from the sample input you provided but fail for other cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/\t(.*),\1/\t\1/g;s/,+\t/\t/g' file | column -ts$'\t'

Sl.no  Name1  Name2  Dis  From  Type  item   Animal    Code
 2     qw     wsa    12   23    car   Case   CAT1,Dog  p.12>a
23     as     swe    34   2     Bus   Case1  Dog1      N.12>a
23     ks     awe    35   .     Bike  Case1  rat4      5.16>b
```

Comment: I suspect the input is not tab delimited, but fixed width, as the first column is right aligned, not left as tab would make it.

Comment: possible but the expected output has a different width, suggesting otherwise.

Comment: That would fail if the duplicated Animal in the first row was `Dog` instead of `CAT1`, i.e. if the cell contained `CAT1,Dog,Dog` instead of `CAT1,CAT1,Dog`. It'd also fail given `CAT1,Dog,CAT1` but idk if that's possible input or not.

Answer (score 2):

Since the input looks like it is fixed-width, you can use [unpack](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack) to split it into columns.  Then split each cell on comma and use [uniq](https://perldoc.perl.org/List::Util#uniq) to remove the duplicates while preserving order.  Then, output it with `pack`.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use List::Util qw(uniq);

my $tmpl = 'A6A6A7A5A6A10A8A15A*';
while (<DATA>) {
    my @cols = unpack $tmpl, $_;
    for my $c (@cols) {
        $c =~ s/^\s+//;
        my @items = split /,/, $c;
        $c = join ',', uniq(@items);
    }
    print pack($tmpl, @cols), "\n";
}

__DATA__
Sl.no Name1 Name2  Dis  From  Type      item    Animal         Code
 2    qw     wsa   12    23   car,car   Case    CAT1,CAT1,Dog  p.12>a,p.12>a
23    as     swe   34    2,2  Bus,Bus   Case1,, Dog1,Dog1,,    N.12>a,N.12>a
23    ks     awe   35    .    Bike,Bike Case1,, rat4,rat4,,    5.16>b,5.16>b
```

Output:

```
Sl.no Name1 Name2  Dis  From  Type      item    Animal         Code
2     qw    wsa    12   23    car       Case    CAT1,Dog       p.12>a
23    as    swe    34   2     Bus       Case1   Dog1           N.12>a
23    ks    awe    35   .     Bike      Case1   rat4           5.16>b
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file is fixed width, and not tab delimited, you can dedupe the fields with a regex. Match any unbroken string of non-whitespace, split on comma, dedupe the result, then join it back with commas. Add spaces for every character removed to fix the formatting.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $hdr = <DATA>;
print $hdr;

while (<DATA>) {
    s/(\S+)/ my %s; my $n = join ',', grep { !$s{$_}++ } split ',', $1; $n .= ' ' x (length($1) - length($n)); $n; /eg;
    print;
}

__DATA__
Sl.no Name1 Name2  Dis  From  Type      item    Animal         Code
 2    qw     wsa   12    23   car,car   Case    CAT1,CAT1,Dog  p.12>a,p.12>a
23    as     swe   34    2,2  Bus,Bus   Case1,, Dog1,Dog1,,    N.12>a,N.12>a
23    ks     awe   35    .    Bike,Bike Case1,, rat4,rat4,,    5.16>b,5.16>b
```

Output:

```
Sl.no Name1 Name2  Dis  From  Type      item    Animal         Code
 2    qw     wsa   12    23   car       Case    CAT1,Dog       p.12>a
23    as     swe   34    2    Bus       Case1   Dog1           N.12>a
23    ks     awe   35    .    Bike      Case1   rat4           5.16>b
```

Answer (score 0):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==1 {
    hdr = $0
    while ( match(hdr,/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/) ) {
        width[++i] = RLENGTH
        hdr = substr(hdr,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
}
{
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        fld = ""
        delete seen
        n = split($i,parts,/,/)
        for ( j=1; j<=n; j++ ) {
            part = parts[j]
            if ( (part != "") && !seen[part]++ ) {
                fld = (fld == "" ? "" : fld ",") part
            }
        }
        printf "%-*s", width[i], fld
    }
    print ""
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Sl.no Name1 Name2  Dis  From  Type      item    Animal         Code
2     qw    wsa    12   23    car       Case    CAT1,Dog       p.12>a
23    as    swe    34   2     Bus       Case1   Dog1           N.12>a
23    ks    awe    35   .     Bike      Case1   rat4           5.16>b
```

The above assumes you don't really want "From" in the header line to start 1 character sooner than the data values below it nor to have "Code" be right-aligned when everything else is left-aligned.